Can't connect to postgres db by pgAdmin installed on my computer
I install with docker-compose.yaml database and pgAdmin.
I run pgadmin on http://localhost:5050/browser/
I connect to the database and everything work great.
But when I try connect to database from gpAdmin installed(copy host, port username, password ) on my computer I got error
Unable to connect to server.
Everything is installed on one machine.
I usin windows.
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"


did you try to connect in console ?

Unable to connect server error is most probably because of the environment variables you defined at compose.yaml file and the values you entered at pgadmin while adding new server do not match with each other. (In case the containers are up and running, and connected with same network. Make sure these steps first.)
It is also recommended to use postgredb password as a secret value. For a basic setup, create a db/password.txt file at the same directory of your compose.yaml file and add single line password there.
compose.yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-c
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=example
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=md5 
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata 
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - pg-network
  pgadmin: 
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin-c
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=your_email@example.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=yourpassword
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks: 
      - pg-network
volumes:
  db-data:
secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt
networks:
  pg-network:
    driver: bridge

docker compose up --build

Navigate to localhost:8080 for PG Admin and add new server.
PgAdmin - Add New Server

General - Name: my-server
Connection - Hostname / address: db (db service at compose)
Connection - port: 5432 (the exposed and default PostgreSQL port at compose)
Connection - Maintanance database: example (db name at compose)
Connection - Username: postgres (db user at compose)
Connection - Password: Resample-Landlady5-Bottle (used for container)

If this doesn't help, it is probably because of the network issue. Make sure containers are running first.
docker ps

After that check networks, it should be created after docker compose up --build
docker network ls

Then, check containers' network:
docker inspect postgres-c -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"

docker inspect pgadmin-c -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"

I hope these helps.
